# How to force docker-compose to re-evaluate labels?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Given a `docker-compose.yml` has the following labels:

```
whoami:
image: containous/whoami
networks:
  - local-proxy
expose:
  - 80
restart: unless-stopped
labels:
  foo: bar
```

..and the docker-compose file is changed to:

```
whoami:
image: containous/whoami
networks:
  - local-proxy
expose:
  - 80
restart: unless-stopped
labels:
  foo: baz
```

What is the best/most effective way to "force" docker-compose to re-apply the new label values?

Comment: Does re-running `docker-compose up -d` not do it?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell; I've also tried a smattering of flags from `--force-rm` `--no-cache`, etc. I'm sure there's some magical combination of flags I'm missing.